# Getting scripts to load only after DOM 100% ready in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm using a Bootstrap template and their HTML and their CSS / JS load order is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>          <html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>          <html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->  <html> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Atropos - Responsive Multipurpose</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5,CSS3,Template" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="Author" content="Dorin Grigoras [www.stepofweb.com]" />

        <!-- mobile settings -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />

        <!-- WEB FONTS -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- CORE CSS -->
        <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/superslides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
        <link href="assets/plugins/revolution-slider/css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- THEME CSS -->
        <link href="assets/css/essentials.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/layout-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/orange.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- orange: default style -->
        <!--<link id="css_dark_skin" href="assets/css/layout-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--><!-- DARK SKIN -->

        <!-- styleswitcher - demo only -->
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/orange.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="orange" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/red.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="red" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/pink.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/yellow.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="yellow" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/darkgreen.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="darkgreen" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/green.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="green" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/darkblue.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="darkblue" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/blue.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/brown.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="brown" />
        <link href="assets/css/color_scheme/lightgrey.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="lightgrey" />
        <!-- /styleswitcher - demo only -->



        <!-- STYLESWITCHER - REMOVE ON PRODUCTION/DEVELOPMENT -->
        <link href="assets/plugins/styleswitcher/styleswitcher.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     

        <!-- Morenizr -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><!-- Available classes for body: boxed , pattern1...pattern10 . Background Image - example add: data-background="assets/images/boxed_background/1.jpg"  -->
```

-- **LOTS OF HTML HERE** --

```
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.isotope.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/masonry.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/stellar/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/knob/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/superslides/dist/jquery.superslides.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/styleswitcher/styleswitcher.js"></script><!-- STYLESWITCHER - REMOVE ON PRODUCTION/DEVELOPMENT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>

    <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/revolution-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/revolution-slider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider_revolution.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>


    <!-- Google Analytics: Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. Go to http://www.google.com/analytics/ for more information. -->
    <!--<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'domainname.com');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    -->

</body>
```

There's quite a bit of JS at the bottom that need to be loaded only after the DOM is 100% ready in the browser.

Unfortunately I'm having a hard time getting the timing right - my page still does not function like the demo does - the Slider doesn't show up, parallax doesn't work, and I'm sure a lot of things also don't work that I haven't noticed. I'm sure this is happening because some DOM nodes don't exist yet by the time the JS (normally all loaded at the bottom) is loaded by Meteor.

**Here's what I've tried:**

NOTE: I would also like to put a lot of these JS files directly into `client/javascripts` so that I can take advantage of Meteor's auto-minifying and bundling feature on production

1 . I figure that after the layout template is rendered is when the DOM should be ready, so I'm going to append the script tags to the body after layout is rendered, but this doesn't work.

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function() {

    console.log('layout rendered');

    var appendToHead = function(array){
        for (index in array){
            $('head').append(array[index]);
        };
    };

    var array = [
      // an array of all the script tags
      '<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>',
      '<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>'
      // etc...
    ];

    appendToHead(array);

});
```

1. I've tried wrapping this function in a `Tracker.afterFlush()` but that's not working either.
2. I've tried putting this function into `main.js` but that's not working.
3. I've tried wrapping this in `Meteor.startup()` and doesn't work.
4. I've even tried wrapping this in `$('document').ready()` and it didn't work.
5. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that even putting everything into its own package won't work, since packages can only control the package load order based on its dependencies on other JS files, but doesn't have the ability to control load order based on DOM status, right?

BTW, I put console logs next to each attempt and here is the order they were fired.

```
code inside Tracker.afterFlush has been fired
code inside main.js has been fired
code inside jQuery document.ready() has been fired
code inside layout.onRendered has been fired
```

Part of the difficulty is the fragmented template nature of Meteor. A piece of JS code (let's say a slideshow) needs a DOM element to exist before it can run. It doesn't make sense to have that code load when the layout is rendered, because the layout is just the layout and won't have the DOM element. The DOM element the slideshow needs is contained in the `{{> intro}}`, `{{> photos}}`, and `{{> videos}}` templates.

But it's also tedious to write code that loads the slideshow JS three separate times for those three separate templates...

What if there are eight different 3rd-party JS scripts that you're using? One template uses four, another uses eight, another uses one, another uses six. It would be a complete pain to have to define EXACTLY which scripts are to load in the `onRendered` callback of each seperate template, over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your main template's rendered() method to load the required JS scripts in given order. Lets say your main template (or top level template) is named as `appLayout` then you can define rendered() method as below.

Place your all JS files in `public\js` folder in your meteor app.

```js
Template.appLayout.rendered = function() {
  if (!window.allScriptsLoaded) {
    var scripts = [
      // list of JS files to be loaded.
      'js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
      'js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js',
      'js/plugin/jquery-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js',
      'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js'
    ];

    function loadNext() {
      var src = scripts.shift();
      if (typeof src === 'undefined')
        return;

      var s = document.createElement("script");

      s.setAttribute('src', src);
      if (s.addEventListener) {
        s.addEventListener("load", loadNext, false);
      } else if (s.readyState) {
        s.onreadystatechange = loadNext;
      }
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    };

    loadNext();
    window.allScriptsLoaded = true;
  }
}
```

This way you can have exact control on load order of your files.

Comment: I would like to continue putting the JS files into the `client` folder to take advantage of Meteor's built-in minification and bundling ability in production.

Comment: If you put things in client, you lose control to meteor, then meteor will minify and bundle your JS and load it automatically. You then do not have control over it.

Comment: I guess there is no way then to take advantage of Meteor's minifying and bundling while still controlling load order in relation to the DOM / templates?

Comment: Not exactly, you can keep things in `client` folder and still have the ordering in your way but in that you need to take care of lot of things ([meteor loading priority](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)) and change in file name, adding/removing files and their place in folder structure may change the order and mess up things for you. Cleaner way is to keep things in `public` and load as you want, example shown by above code.

Comment: I see. Would you happen to know a atmosphere package that can also bundle+minify things in /public ? I have a lot of little files here and there and would like to just consolidate everything into as few minified files as possible