# How to control the bundling order of CSS in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've got the Bootstrap package installed and a custom template that gave me about 10 other CSS files.

When I put all the CSS files into `client/styles` Meteor bundles and minifies all the CSS, which is nice.

BUT the bundle / load order matters tremendously. Because, you know, they're *cascading*.

What's the bundling order that Meteor takes for CSS files in `client`?

Is the only way to control it is to rename all my stylesheet files with numbers?

```
100-my_style_that_overwrites_some_bootstrap_defaults.css
110-some_other_styles.css
120-lol.css
```

And then the order that the CSS would be bundled is:

```
1. bootstrap.css from the bootstrap package
2. 100-my...
3. 110-some...
4. 120-lol...
```

Is there a more elegant of practical way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS is ordered according to the file load order (adjusted slightly from the Meteor docs to account for only the CSS files):

> There are several load ordering rules. They are applied sequentially
>   to all applicable files in the application, in the priority given
>   below:
>
> 1. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
> 2. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
> 3. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
> 4. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

You can put the files you want to load first in the `lib` directory or use the file naming convention in your question.

For full grained control you would have to create a package and you could explicitly define how you want the css files to load.

1. Create a package:

In your Meteor project directory

```
meteor create --package styles
```

2. In the `packages/styles` directory you will have a `package.js` file where you can explicitly define loading order.

Once you've moved your css files into the `/packages/styles` directory you can use the order you define, in the `Package.onUse` method:

```
api.addFiles([
    'bootstrap.css',
    '100-my...css',
    '110-some...css',
    '120-lol.css'
], 'client');
```

Note you may consider this convention to be awkward but it can help if you want to easily swap themes in your app, you can easily remove the package and add another.

Finally add the package into your app, or rather make your app acknowledge it:

```
meteor add styles
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I make sure that these CSS files load after the bootstrap.css file that is included in a separate Bootstrap atmosphere package? Also, the CSS files reference external image files in other folders for background images and stuff. I put all the CSS files into the `/packages/styles` directory, but what about the images?

Comment: You can use `api.use("tbs:boostrap")`" to make it use another package first. For images add them as normal using `api.addFiles` just like the css files.

Comment: Hey @Akshat would you mind giving this other question of mine a look?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661370/getting-scripts-to-load-only-after-dom-100-ready-in-meteor/30663990#30663990